# CreateIfNotExistsAsync - This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am using Microsoft sample client app that puts an image in blob storage.

It works on my laptop but when I place it in my Azure VM Windows service I get the following error:

```
ERROR: This request is not authorized to perform this operation. -    at 
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.<CreateIfNotExistsAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Both ip addresses (laptop and vm) have been added to firewall settings.

I am using the same access key for both. I also tried the second key.

```
            string containerName = ContainerPrefix + Guid.NewGuid();
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString();
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        try
        {
            BlobRequestOptions requestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new NoRetry() };
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(requestOptions, null);
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace}");
            Console.ReadLine();
            throw;
        }
```

Thoughts?

Gina

Comment: Since it's using the internal network whitelisting the public ip will not allow traffic to it. To properly setup the firewall you should add the virtual network of the VM to the firewall setttings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Allow access from : All networks to eliminate possibility of IP address issue.

[image]

Comment: i will give it a try but why is Azure blocked but the internet is open? Again, my son's laptop from 2015 can run it but I can't from within Azure?

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for but probably better suited for Serverfault. This worked but I will eventually need to know how to setup azure correctly.

Comment: Double check the public  IP of the VM and make sure its the same you whitelisted.